# Checking understanding of the ping -t TTL flag

Tags: ping, ttl

I'm checking for comprehension on a homework question for my class.  I looked over the man pages for `ping` and the `-t` flag didn't have a lot of info on it so I had to infer quite a bit.  If someone could verify that my understanding is correct, and perhaps point me to a resource that explains `-t` flag better than the man pages, I'd appreciate it.

**The question:**

> Write a bash command line that will verify that no more than two network devices are used to pass messages from the `syccuxas01.pcc.edu` server to the `www.pcc.edu` server. Use `ping` with the `-t` option and see the TTL Details section of `man ping`.
>
> ```
> ping -t 2 www.pcc.edu
> ```

**My understanding of what that command means and thoughts:** The question is poorly worded as "network devices" would be more accurately described as hops. Hops are the steps that a packet of information takes to get to the server you want to send it to, much like if you're going on a car trip, you'll drive through other towns along the way to your destination.

So if we ping the TTL (time to live, which is very dramatic sounding!) [ aka -t ] twice, we're able to get results, which means that there are 2 "hops" to get to `www.pcc.edu` from the server we access through Putty. TTL from what I understand means how many hops the ping will try to use to send a packet. So `ping -t 1 www.pcc.edu` will fail. `ping -t 3 www.pcc.edu` will succeed, but it's using 3 hops, which is not what we want to solve the problem.